# Writting to a single file from multithread with c++ (on cluster)

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am running a mpi programme on a cluster.
In the program, I am trying to write the result of each processor to a single output file. Each processor figures out in which part of the file it should write into.
Everything goes well when I run the program on a single PC using multi thread. However, most part of the result is damaged when I implement the program on the cluster.The cluster write to a net disk(dell MD3000). The net disk is connected to each computer using nfs.

Is there anybody know the reason?

Comment: How exactly are you performing the write?

Comment: did you forget the ssh part?

Comment: Have you tried running one instance of your program on the cluster? If that doesn't work then it's likely not multithreading that's causing the problem but something else.

Comment: Yes, one instance runs well. It also runs well when I run multiple threads on single computer from the cluster. @Brett

Comment: The ssh goes well @Bot.